# How to extract a value out of a file, and save it in a new file, using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I recently started using Powershell and I'm trying out some code.
I have a .cfg file with several rules of code. The code is written like this:

```
ad.name=1
ad.virtual=active
ad.set=none
ad.partition=78
```

Now I want to export the value of *ad.partition*, which is *78*, to a new file. I don't want to export *ad.partition* or *=* but only the number 78.

So far I got this:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\file.cfg | Where-Object {$_ -like 'ad.partition=78'}
```

But then I -obviously- just get the variable and the value. Not sure how to continue...
I hope someone has a way of achieving what I want.

After saving the value in a new file, would it be possible to add spaces? For example, the value consists out of 9 digits, e.g. *123456789*. The desired output result would be *123 456 789*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select-String` cmdlet to *capture* your desired value using a *regex*. Then just pipe the result to the *Out-File* cmdlet. To get your desired output with spaces, you can use a simple format string:

```
"{0:### ### ###}" -f [int](Select-string 'ad\.partition=(.*)' -Path C:\file.cfg).Matches.Groups[1].Value | 
    Out-File C:\result.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to add spaces in the destination file (result.cfg)? The value exists out of 9 digits. The preferred outcome would be: 111 222 333.

Comment: can you add an example of the value in the source and your desired output?

Comment: Source value: ad.partition=123456789 - desired output: 123 456 789

Comment: @Codemeister You should include this information in the question, not in a comment

Comment: I agree @Paolo, this should be part of your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandl This gives the incorrect output if, say, `ad.partition=7898`

Comment: You are right, in case the value has less then 9 digits, the output might be not as desired. If that is the case, Codemeister should add further details to the question.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Yeah, I think the whole digits thing should have either been clear from the beginning, or been a different question altogether. Oh well

Comment: @Paolo 100% agree. Also I like your approach with the ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet to create a hash table from your file, then simply index the key you are after:

```
$h=(Get-Content -Path C:\file.cfg | ConvertFrom-StringData)
$h.("ad.partition") -replace ('^(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,3})?','$1 $2 $3') > C:\out.cfg
```